# Question title mangled in "Hot Network Questions"

Tags: bug

I was browsing another stack exchange community (*space*, if it makes a difference) and a unix question with mangled title appeared in the *Hot Network Questions* list.

Question: [Add path to $PATH if not already in $PATH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217622/add-path-to-path-if-not-already-in-path)

[image]

Looks like MathJaX being overzealous, but it's weird to see it enabled for questions of other communities.

I'm not even sure this is the right place to report, but since it was a unix question that broke the thing...

Comment: That's not a bug with [unix.se]. You should report this either on [meta.space.se] or on [meta.se]. Except that it's already been reported on the main meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229363/exclude-tex-se-question-titles-from-mathjax-parsing-in-hot-network-questions

Comment: Going to close since it's already reported on the main meta